# Finding a list of 'domain specific related words' from a given word

Tags: nlp

Is there a API which gives me a domain specific related words when I give it a word.

I mean, I provide the system with 'Artificial Intelligence' in returns me words like 'Neural Network','Supervised learning','Hill Climbing' and many others.

If none available out of the box, is making this thing possible? If it is, what resource should I be consulting to build this thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is very broad question, but there is a api/system/resource called WordNet which can help. It is a semantic database in the form of the complex semantic graph, where concepts (word meanings) are nodes, and edges represent conceptual similarity. By quering a particular nodes neighbours by some relations you can get such information.

For english language, there is a Princeton Wordnet: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

And querying wordnet like databases can be made by hand, or using some existing tools/apis, like eg. WQuery: http://wquery.org/

This covers very broad domains set, so may not be the best solution if you can enumerate domains in which you are interested in. In such case some crawling of Wikipedia may be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a resource that returns semantically related words, I've just recently developed an API that takes a query and returns semantically related words. It offers parts of speech, relationships to the query word, and a word similarity measurement. It should do pretty well at domain-related results.

https://kiingo.co/rapid-associations-api

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try spacy sense2vec, which gives words similar in context -
https://explosion.ai/demos/sense2vec?word=artificial%20intelligence&sense=auto&model=2015